# How To Store User Input with Discord.py/Creating a text based game bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Now I've been trying to create a text based game with my discord.py bot. It's the rewrite version. But unfortunately, I don't know how to store each individual's game data. Basically their input data and their progress and stuff. THis is all I have

```
@client.command()
async def gamecreate(ctx, arg):
    if arg == None:
        await ctx.send("Please name your new game")
    elif arg == bad_word:
        await ctx.send("I'm sorry but that name is not available.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Now please name your character with the {name command")
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to create a class and instanciate every user, but it won't be efficient with a lot of players. A more efficient way would be to store data in a `json file` and to use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library. If you have a lot of players, the most efficient way would be to use a database and a database library like `sqlite3` or `mongodb`.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to solve this issue, for low stakes scenarios I would advise using a json file and the python [json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or in more important situations I would use sqlite3 and the python [sqlite3 library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)